# C# NullReferenceException with static class

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a static class:

```
namespace GVN  
{  
    static class ClData      
    {  
        public static string cltNM {get; set;}  
    }  
}
```

But, when I try to use it,

```
label_nm.Text = ClData.cltNM;
```

this error appears: ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/sxw2ez55 )

Even if I perform this manually:

```
ClData.cltNM = "12345";
```

Before:

```
label_nm.Text = ClData.cltNM;
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: @DJKRAZE create an instance of a static class .. ?

Comment: Please try to use better variable names.  Highly abbreviated names make reading code much harder than it needs to be, and code completion tools mean you don't actually need to type out long names.

Comment: A class can be declared static, indicating that it contains only static members. It is not possible to create instances of a static class using the new keyword.

 The main features of a static class are:

    They only contain static members.

    They cannot be instantiated.

    They are sealed.

    They cannot contain Instance Constructors must Be static

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `label_nm` is `null`, rather than the `static` `string` variable, or the error is not in fact on the line of code that you've indicated.  Even if  `cltNM` is `null` it wouldn't throw a null reference exception on that line.

Comment: I did not notice that. Thank you!